# python extract email addresses from html file into another file

Tags: html, python-3.4

Basically what I'm trying to do is the following:

I've downloaded an HTML file and within this file contains a load of text and loads of different email addresses. What I would like to do is to only gather the email addresses from this file and input into 1 excel file using Python 3.4. Would anybody be able to help with that?

The HTML file looks like this:

```
    <span style="display: none;"></span>
</td>
<td>Customer Care 
- <a href="?team_search=Team%20Resera" >Team Resera</a>
<br>(<a href="team.html?orgunit_id=50012581">team page &amp; map</a>)
</td>
<td>Berlin (BER2): Sesamestreet 11-12 </td>
<td><a href="mailto:blablabla.@blabla.com">blablabla.blabla@blabla.com</a><br />
(<a href="jabber://blablabla.blabla@blabla.com">jabber</a>)
(<a href="xmpp://blablabla.blabla@blabla.com">xmpp</a>)
</td>
<td>
        work: <a href="tel:72496532">72496532</a> (<a href="skype:72496532">Skype</a>)<br />
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started, from the example html it outputs

```
import re
file = open('example.html')
line = file.readline()
while line:
    line = file.readline()
    if bool(re.search(r'([\w.])+@([\w.])+', line)):
        email = line.split('//',1)[-1]
        email = email.split('\"',1)[0]
        print email
file.close()
#outputs blablabla.blabla@blabla.com
```

Comment: That works awesome :) . Thank you so much! I have sooo much to learn as a newbie.....*sigh*